# Excel/PowerBI OData import gives internal server error 500

Tags: excel, server, odata, powerbi, navision

I have Navision server up and running and I want to extract some data from it using Excel/Power BI and OData feed.

If (in Excel) I import Get External Data ->Other Sources -> OData Data Feed, I use Navision generated OData link and it succesfully imports data using Windows Authentification, but if I use New Query -> Other Sources -> OData Feed I input the same link and the same user and it gives:

> Details: "Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Resources.HttpResource: Request failed:
>
> OData Version: 3 and 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (500) 
>   Internal Server Error. (An error has occurred.)
>
> OData Version: 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. (An error has occurred.)"

Same issue when connecting with through PowerBI
I've tried using local NAV user and Basic authentication and the issue is still the same.

OData and SOAP services are enabled.

EDIT: When connecting using local NAV account with Basic authentication it says "We couldn't authenticate with the provided credentials" even though the users are created the same

Comment: Check windows event viewer on Nav server. Maybe additional information about error is posted there when error happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding Alternative Tenant ID's to NAV instance tenants and adding  those Alt ID's to hosts

Comment: Similar solution here, with a more detailed explanation: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Unable-to-connect-to-NAV-using-ODAta/m-p/148473/highlight/true#M65053